# The website in local is different from the online website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, dreamweaver

I uploaded a website on my hosting space and I realized the website in local is different from the online website.

- This is the local version, I'm debugging it with dreamweaver, and checking the responsive behaviour with Google devTools. So everything is fine, the navigation bar collapses, font size is 24px, bootstrap behaviour is ok.

  [image]
- This is the online version, and I'm checking the responsive behaviour with Google devTools too. The navigation bar doesn't collapse, font size is 24px too but it's too small, bootstrap behaviour is not happening.

  [image]

Why this behaviour?

Comment: add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: paths to resources are incorrect — what errors do you see in the console?

Comment: @ScottSimpson no error i swear

Comment: why downvotes? it was a serious trouble for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this into the `<head>` tag to make it responsive:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```